# Gloabl Seed and Operation Seed in Tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

What is the difference between Global Seed and Operation Seed in TensorFlow.

According to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed)

While explaining Global Seed, they mention this

> If the **global seed** is set but the **operation seed** is not set, *we get
> different results for every call to the random op, but the same
> sequence for every re-run of the program*:

and while explaining Operation Seed, they again state, something similiar

> If the **operation seed** is set, *we get different results for every call
> to the random op, but the same sequence for every re-run of the
> program*:

what are the main differences between the two...and how do they operate at a intuitive level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good decription of the differences: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/tensorflow.set_random_seed

In short, `tf.random.set_seed` or `tf.set_random_seed` will guarantee that all operations will produce repeatable results across sessions. It will set the operation-seed deterministically for every operation.

Setting operation seed makes sense only as part of operation definition `tf.random_uniform([1], seed=1)` and will also lead to same sequences produced by this op across sessions.

What is the difference?

- graph-seed makes all ops repeatedly deterministic. Use it if you want to fix all ops. Different ops will still produce different sequences (but repeated across sessions)
- operation-seed makes single operation deterministic. You can create 2 ops that will produce same sequences.